# Python/Keras/Neural Networks - Basics to make it run

Tags: python, keras

I'm a beginner working with Keras to make predictions.
I understand the concept and all the theory behind it. But I'm having a hard time to make it run. At this stage I'm not worried about the efficiency of it, I just want to run it and see an output so I can evolve later.

I have this dummy Pandas DataFrame I'm using as predictor_train (X):

```
                 Value        1lag        2lag        3lag        4lag...
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01  231.721933  165.195418  170.418903  225.892387  206.282539   
2005-05-01  163.259812  231.721933  165.195418  170.418903  225.892387   
2005-06-01  211.649963  163.259812  231.721933  165.195418  170.418903   
2005-07-01  249.054951  211.649963  163.259812  231.721933  165.195418   
2005-08-01  168.657539  249.054951  211.649963  163.259812  231.721933   
2005-09-01  179.623448  168.657539  249.054951  211.649963  163.259812   
2005-10-01  228.437842  179.623448  168.657539  249.054951  211.649963   
2005-11-01  165.805266  228.437842  179.623448  168.657539  249.054951
...
[129 rows x 96 columns]
```

I have this other DataFrame which I'm using as target_train (Y):

```
Date
2005-04-01   -0.01136
2005-05-01    0.04713
2005-06-01    0.00329
2005-07-01   -0.00985
2005-08-01    0.05635
2005-09-01   -0.03766
2005-10-01    0.01848
2005-11-01   -0.01387
[129 rows x 1 column]
```

I'm using the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation


model=Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(output_dim=64, input_dim=100, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("tanh"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=10, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="rmsprop")
model.fit(predictor_train, target_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32,show_accuracy=True)
prediction=model.predict(predictor_train)

print prediction
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/file.py", line 1271, in var_neural_reg1
model.fit(predictor_train, target_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32,show_accuracy=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 581, in fit
shuffle=shuffle, metrics=metrics)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 230, in _fit
ins_batch = slice_X(ins, batch_ids)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 65, in slice_X
return [x[start] for x in X]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1908, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_array(key)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1953, in _getitem_array
return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1370, in take
convert=True, verify=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3508, in take
indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1721, in maybe_convert_indices
raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Any insights on how to make this mammoth move?

Comment: Input dim needs to match the dimensions of your training data.  I imagine Keras is attempting to train on your 100 column specifications with only 96 columns of data.

Comment: so, where it says "input_dim=100" I should substitute for "input_dim=129"? (129 is the number of columns in my predictor series) @CharlieHaley

Comment: Your data up there says it's 96 columns and 129 rows, so I would think 96.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you don't want to set your `input_dim` to 129.  That's just the number of samples.  Keras doesn't really care if your data has 1 row or 1 million rows; that's not the dimensionality of your data.  If your data were a numpy array, the input shape would be (1, 2, 3) = (2, 3).  The number of rows (1) doesn't make a difference.

But, that's not the issue here.  The error that you're receiving doesn't have to do with your specified dimensionality.  If that were the case, then you'd be receiving a different error (`ValueError` and not `IndexError`) that traces to your backend (Theano or Tensorflow), if there was in fact a shape mismatch between your data and what you specified in the model.  For example:

```
ValueError: ('shapes (x,x) and (x,x) not aligned: x (dim 1) != x (dim 0)', (x, x), (x, x))
```

Looking at the error message, this is a problem with how you're preprocessing your data; i.e., the problem is with pandas and not with Keras.  You're using Keras' `slice_X` function to segment your data, but when Keras talks to pandas and tells it that you want to get the data from `dataframe[x:y]`, pandas is responding that the indices you've specified aren't valid given your dataframe.

After that's sorted, though, you might run into different errors once your program gets to the Keras functions that you're calling in `model.fit`.  Specifically, you'll probably see a shape mismatch between your data and what your model is expecting.  How are your columns being encoded before being fed into your Keras model?  [Keras is expecting a numpy array](http://keras.io/models/#methods) for `X` and `y` in `model.fit`.  Also, what kind of output are you expecting such that `output_dim = 10`?

I recommend [this Keras example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py) that shows sequence to sequence prediction with an LSTM model, in this case learning addition, since it does exactly what you want; i.e., it's concrete example that shows the model running and evolving at every epoch.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Iteration 1
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
45000/45000 [==============================] - 30s - loss: 1.6745 - acc:0.3927- val_loss: 1.5373 - val_acc: 0.4320
Q 58333+69862
T 128195
☒ 13335 
---
.
.
.
---
Q 83911+65   
T 83976 
☒ 11115 
---
```

The model starts learning what's up around epoch 7:

```
Iteration 7
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
45000/45000 [==============================] - 31s - loss: 0.9129 - acc: 0.6549 - val_loss: 0.9117 - val_acc: 0.6510
Q 80+3375    
T 3455  
☒ 3420  
---
.
.
.
---
Q 6+50853    
T 50859 
☑ 50859    <--------------------------
---
```

You can add the following print line to the `decode` function in the `CharacterTable` class to the following in order to see what's happening.  In this case, the source addition questions are inputted in reverse, which improves performance in this type of model by introducing short term dependencies between the inputs and targets ([Sutskever, Vinyals, and Le 2014](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf))

```
    def decode(self, X, calc_argmax=True):
        if calc_argmax:
            X = X.argmax(axis=-1)
        print('{0} --> {1}'.format(X, [self.indices_char[x] for x in X]))
        return ''.join(self.indices_char[x] for x in X)
```

For example:

```
Iteration 3
Train on 45000 samples, validate on 5000 samples
Epoch 1/1
45000/45000 [==============================] - 21s - loss: 1.4865 - acc: 0.4491 - val_loss: 1.4132 - val_acc: 0.4676
[ 0 11 12  2  4 11 12] --> [' ', '7', '8', '+', '0', '7', '8']
[13  9 11  0] --> ['9', '5', '7', ' ']
[12  4 11  0] --> ['8', '0', '7', ' ']
Q 870+87 
T 957 
☒ 807 
---
[ 0  8 10  3  8  4 10] --> [' ', '4', '6', '-', '4', '0', '6']
[9 8 4 0] --> ['5', '4', '0', ' ']
[10  4 13  0] --> ['6', '0', '9', ' ']
Q 604-64 
T 540 
☒ 609 
---
```

This encoder/decoder model can be changed quite easily to adapt to other kinds of sequence to sequence prediction problems.

You'd probably want to revise the code to fit your data.  But, in your case, if you were going to feed the above data into the model as it is, I believe your `input_dim` would be `len('0123456789.- ')`, since that's the dimensionality of your data; i.e., the set of all characters in your inputs and targets.  In this linked example, sequences are converted to one-hot encodings of the individual characters.

So, you'd specify an input shape in the first layer of the model:

```
model.add(LSTM(HIDDEN_DIMENSIONS, input_shape=(MAX_LENGTH, INPUT_DIMENSIONALITY)))
```